# Wrong thread waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, wait

I'm trying to read data from a socket, however this thread is not the only thread reading. The second thread listens for commands being sent. What I want to do is get the thread that listens for commands to wait until I'm done on the second thread.
The problem is that the command listening thread is not waiting, instead the other thread that I want to listen waits.

This is the method being run by the thread I don't want to wait

```
public void sendMessage(Message message) {
   pauseListener(true);
   try {
   //Inform the receiver that a message is to be sent
      System.out.println("Sending message");
   sendFunction(Function.SND_MESSAGE);
   //And wait for a response, OK will allow for sending of data
   System.out.println("Awaiting confirmation");
   Error status = readError();
   if(status == Error.OK) {
      System.out.println("Sending message data");
      //Send the data
      sendBytes(message.getSender().getBytes(), 0);
      byte[] byteLong = Long.toString(message.getID()).getBytes();
      sendBytes(byteLong, 0);
      sendBytes(message.getData().getBytes(), 0);
      sendError(Error.OK);
   } else {
      //TODO error handling
      System.err.println("Failed to send message: " + status.name());
   }
   } catch (Exception e) {
      //TODO Error stuff
      System.err.println("An error occured sending message");
      e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
      pauseListener(false);
  }

}
```

The method pause listener is meant to cause the listen to wait, I'm pretty new to working with threads so any advice would be appreciated. The **self.wait()** is set to be the instance of the Thread I want to wait

```
public void pauseListener(boolean pause) {
   synchronized (self) {
      try {
         if(pause) {
            self.wait();
         } else {
            self.notify();
         }
      }catch(InterruptedException e) {
         System.err.println("Failed to suspend listener on client:" + socket);
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

}
```

This is the run() of the thread I'm trying to get to wait.

```
public void run() {
   //Listen for commands
   self = Thread.currentThread();
   while(true) {
   System.out.println("Awaiting instruction");
   Function function;
   try {
      function = readFunction();
   } catch (UnkownCommandException e) {
      e.printUserFriendly();
      e.printStackTrace();
      continue; //Skip the unknown function
   }

   switch (function) {
     case SND_MESSAGE: //Prepare to receive a message
        System.out.println("Receiving message");
        Message input = readMessage();
        if(server != null) {
           server.broadCast(input);
        } else {
           System.out.println(input.toString());
        }

        break;

     default:
        System.out.println("Unknown function: " + function.name());
        break;
     }
   }
}
```

If you need any more information I can give it. Any help would be appreciated, could do with a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: So... you're calling `wait()`, but you're surprised that it waits?

Comment: I want the other thread to wait. The thread defined in self does not wait, the thread that told it to wait, waits

Comment: That's not how any of this works. You can't just tell a thread to stop doing what it's doing; they need to coordinate. I don't mean to be rude, but I think you're in over your head.

Comment: Nah, I appreciate your honesty, thanks, will head back to the planning phase

Comment: Consider creating a shared boolean variable to signal the other thread when it should be listening.

Comment: you said there are 2 threads listening commands, but  provided only one `run()` method. Does the second thread executes the same `run()` method? This is very bad. Only one thread should listen to a socket and decode messages. Then it can decide to pass some messages to another thread.

Comment: What @AlexeiKaigorodov says.  Use an appropriate protocol so that commands can be parsed out of the data stream without messing with thread contentions that will probably never work as you wish.   Your design is broken:(